# Flutter: Is there any possibility to debug/test RevenueCat integration with Google Play internal testing?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console, revenuecat

I am adding **in-app-purchase** to my Android (Flutter) app with RevenueCat.

I have created an **internal** testing track on the Google Play console.

When I run my app from VS Code on a real device in debug mode, I see products added on the Google Play console. But when I tried to purchase one, I got an exception:

```
ERROR(29478): ‼️ BillingWrapper purchases failed to update: DebugMessage: 
Please ensure the specific App version has been published.. ErrorCode: DEVELOPER_ERROR.null
```

So, how I can test/debug my code related to in-app-purchase with RevenueCat?

I understand, that **closed** testing track should be created, which requires review. But there will be functionality (in-app-purchase), that is not tested and probably does not work.

It is my first app and I don't completely understand what is the purpose of Google Play review before closed testing. Will some broken functionality prevent the app from being accepted?

Should I release my app on closed testing without in-app-purchase to increase chances to pass review and then add it in the next release?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote package [purchases_flutter_mock](https://github.com/bigbott/purchases_flutter_mock).

It doesn't cover all purchases_flutter API, but only what I needed at the moment. Still can be a good point to start.